# Search on a literal comma (string) in Google apps script

Tags: string, google-apps-script, replace

I'm using a script to retrieve items from Google Calendar and put it into Google Sheets. In my agenda, I've formatted the calendar items that I want to retrieve in a comma separated fashion as follows:
**Client, Project, Activities.**

Now, I want to retrieve ONLY the agenda items that contain a comma in the title (or, better yet, ultimately two comma's), but I cannot find a way to search on comma's as a string. I use the "search" function, and replacing the comma with a word, perfectly filters only the items with that word. But searching on just the comma (or any other special character) doesn't work. I tried dozens of combinations, including REGEX expressions, but nothing works. Part of the problematic code:

I'm using a script to retrieve items from Google Calendar and put it into Google Sheets. In my agenda, I've formatted the calendar items that I want to retrieve in a comma separated fashion as follows:
**Client, Project, Activities.**

Now, I want to retrieve ONLY the agenda items that contain a comma in the title (or, better yet, ultimately two comma's, separated bij any character or characters), but I cannot find a way to search on comma's as a string. I use the "search" function, and replacing the comma with a word, perfectly filters only the items with that word. But searching on just the comma (or any other special character) doesn't work. I tried dozens of combinations, including REGEX expressions, but nothing works. My code so far:

```
function getCalendarEvents() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Brondata"); 
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mail@domain."); 
  var eind = new Date;
  eind.setDate(eind.getDate()+1);
  var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("1/1/2022"), eind, {search: '(/,{2}/)'});
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(3, 1, lr,14).clearContent();
  var result = []
  events.forEach(e => {
    result.push([e.getStartTime(),
                e.getEndTime(),
                e.getTitle(),
                e.getDescription(),
                e.getDateCreated(),
                e.getLastUpdated(),
                e.isRecurringEvent(),
                e.getCreators()])
  })
  ss.getRange(3,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
}
```

What code do I need to use after the "search" command, to find only the items that contain a comma?

Some things I've tried:

```
'\,' (filters out nothing)
'==\,' (filters out nothing)
'"\,"' (filters out a bit more, but I can't figure out what exactly)
'"==\,"' (same result as previous)
```

Updated the script with the input of @TheWizEd, and it now runs fine perfectly! The complete, working script is as follows:

```
function getCalendarEvents() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Brondata"); 
  let cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  let eind = new Date();
  eind.setDate(eind.getDate()+1);
  let events = cal.getEvents(new Date("1,1,2022"), eind);
  let lr = ss.getLastRow();
  ss.getRange(3, 1, lr,14).clearContent();
  let result = []
  let match = events.filter( e =>  { if( e.getTitle().match(".*\,.*\,") !== null ) return e; } );
  if( match ) {
    match.forEach(e => {
      let title = e.getTitle();
      let codes = [];
        for( let i=0; i<title.length; i++ ) {
          codes.push( title.charCodeAt(i) );
        }
      result.push([e.getStartTime(),
                  e.getEndTime(),
                  e.getTitle(),
                  e.getDescription(),
                  e.getDateCreated(),
                  e.getLastUpdated(),
                  e.isRecurringEvent(),
                  e.getCreators()])
    })
  ss.getRange(3,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result)
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between the comma in the `calendar items that I want to retrieve in a comma separated fashion` and the comma in `agenda items that contain a comma in the title`?

Comment: I don't think I understand you question... I've elaborated my question: I want to be able to filter out only the Google Calendar items that contain a comma...

Comment: But you say they are comma delimitied and you want the agenda that contains commas.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I’m not using the comma’s as a delimiter, in the code: I just want to only import calendar items that contain two comma’s: no need to split or join or something like that.  
The search command works fine if I use it to filter out items with specific string that exist of normal characters. For example: if I search for ‘coffee bar’, only my appointments in a coffee bar are shown. Works flawlessly. But if I use a punctuation character (a dot or a comma) than it ignores it and shows every appointment; also the ones without any comma.

Comment: Have you tried /,{2}/g.  Here is a good site to test [regex](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: The regex you provided didn't work either, but it DID help me understand what happens in that search function: it appears it searches in *all* calendar fields; also the ones I did not retrieve. There doesn't seem to be a way in App Script to search in just the titles of calendar items, so I think I have to find another way to extract de data I want... Thank you VERY much for you help @TheWizEd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Descrition**

I have created 3 events in my calander that have "Test, event *, ***" in the title with and without spaces.  This example script will find all event with that in there title.

**Code.gs**

```
function getCalanderEvent() { 
  try {
    let cal = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    let start = new Date("1,1,2022");
    let end = new Date();
    let events = cal.getEvents(start,end);
    let match = events.filter( event =>  { if( event.getTitle().match(/.*\,.*\,/) !== null ) return event; } );
    if( match ) {
      match.forEach( event => {
          let title = event.getTitle();
          console.log(title);
        }
      );
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
3:20:56 AM  Notice  Execution started
3:20:56 AM  Info    Test, event one, test
3:20:56 AM  Info    Test, event 3, test
3:20:56 AM  Info    Test,event,two
3:20:56 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [RegExr regex tester](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and efforts @TheWizEd! That seems like a nice piece of code! I've tried to implement it, but am apparently too new and inexperienced to be able to fully understand and make use of it. I've updated my question with the complete code I've got so far.

Comment: I've also added 'your' search string in the code, but then only 10 items (out of ±360 items) are found.

Comment: Furthermore: the search string you use will definitely find events that are written like the test events you've tried it on: Test,,event1. But would it also find events like: Test,Projectname,event1?

Comment: I've updated my script to suit your situation.

Comment: Thanks again!! I've updated my script with your input (see my original question: I've added the new code), but get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined getCalendarEvents2 @ Urenoverzicht.gs:45. When I change "match.forEach" in "events.forEach" the script works, but the filter is obviously not applied.

Comment: It works for me.  Did you try exactly as I showed `match.forEach( event => console.log(event.getTitle()) );` without `ss.getRange().setValues()`?

Comment: I now copy pasted the exact code. But I do not see any events in the log: they all seem empty. All I see in de log is: 
"15 jun. 2022 08:56:12 Informatie Wed Jun 15 08:56:11 GMT+02:00 2022" Maybe some region specific code difference? Also tried "new Date("1/1/2022")" but that did not make a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a newbie in coding, so maybe not easy to coach :-) Appreciate it though! I'm now searching for a way to print the result of your code into a spreadsheet...

Comment: (but that indeed is an off topic question)

Comment: I realized a small mistake.  I edited my script to change `let match = true;` to `let match = events;`

Comment: I ran your script again (and also implemented it in my code: see the second code snippet in my question). It runs fine, and it really helps me, slowly but surely, to understand the coding. But it still results in printing ALL the calendar events, not the filtered ones. Probably because the actual filter is still commented out in your code? Also: is there a reason you use the undefined `results` in `console.log(results.length)`?

Comment: No just left over from my previous tests.  I was just trying to confirm that your words are seperated by comma code 44.  What did you find?

Comment: It still returns my complete agenda: does result in showing just the items with two comma's. I've added (a link to) a screenshot to illustrate it.

Comment: In your updated script uncomment `// let match = events.filter(` to become `let match = events.filter(`.  I had commented this so that we could see what characters are in the titles.

Comment: It works, but zero results are returned. I now know why: `match(/,\w+,/)` should be replaced with `match(".*\,.*\,")` . Then it filters out all events with two or more occurrences of a comma character perfectly!

Comment: Mine breaks if there is a space between comma or words.  I'm glad you finally found a solution.

Comment: Hmm... strange. Works perfectly for me, and makes the code even faster, because now it only need to print about half of the events. I've updated my post with the correct code: thanks @TheWizEd! I suppose I can mark your contribution as an answer, as soon as you've uncommented an adjusted the `match`-part of the code?

Comment: I've edited my script to include your regex expression with several examples.

Comment: Thanks! Marked your contribution as answer.